# Is there a way to place an "xsl:value-of" into an inline string?

Tags: xml, xslt

Ok here is an example what I'm trying to accomplish:

`<div class="testClass1 {place xsl:value-of HERE}"> </div>` Is there any way to pull something like this off in XML/XSLT?

Basically I just need to create an option to set the class for a wrapping div in XML... Not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an [Attribute-value-template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template):

```
<div class="testClass1 {xpath-expression}"> </div>
```

...or an  [xsl:attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes).

```
<div>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">testClass1 <xsl:value-of select="{xpath-expression}"/></xsl:attribute>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always go with

```
<div>
   <xsl:attribute name="class">testClass1 <xsl:value-of select="..." /></xsl:attribute>
<div>
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to make much sense to me on two accounts. First, a trivial syntax error, it should be `<xsl:value-of select="some/xpath/expression"/>`. Second, an XPath expression that fits into that `select="..."` also fits, as far as I can see, in an AVT (attribute value template), which is more concise, and hence preferable.